# EWS using OAuth says "Das Format des Wertes Bearer ... ist ungültig"

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices

i am trying to access my mailbox via ExchangeWebService using OAuth. I followed the instructions based on this page: "https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth".

This is my code:

```
        pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions()
        {
            TenantId = "<my tenantID>",
            ClientId = "<my ClientID>"
        };

        pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

        // The permission scope required for EWS access
        ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

        service = new ExchangeService();

        // Make the interactive token request
        var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
```

Up to this Point, evrything seems allright. The method "AcquireTokenInteractive" opens a ne windows from Microsoft where i can choose my mailaccount from my organization. The variable "authResult" ist filled and contains a new "AccessToken".

The problem starts here:

```
var folders = await service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
```

This method causes an exception:

> Das Format des Werts "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImRIUXhxTlczdlpDeVM3ZGZrZVZyNlZUQ2xwRU1JWURoMmE5LVgxaEFLMGsiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImpTMVhvMU9XRGpfNTJ2YndHTmd2UU8yVnpNYyIsImtpZCI6ImpTMVhvMU9XRGpfNTJ2YndHTmd2UU8yVnpNYyJ9.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.K6xGoZEMW19JsC-ZSrnUrgF8s8eQv_qwFBZzDELMHnikgZzqDwUEd7_41eAL5hDiKMLTfOfqMrjoVqHViqMic7wyY1QOlx9Kzz6vYTuqMFwYOdevwhEAOgH7uMzCE08c-Wu35UPV_vxWqZfGLLRgJHqTFaUWz0kkdtXk1vLs5MDvWL8CYwXq8gHzM2Mhh8wtB-ZIrjSAHtsrSt43KkBe-cP5PJvqvsyvm4lf-ajKxQtFj0Q4uc8YcCume0suiBgCltxuMcz4uP4OAFgGrbZ04BB33GLDwwFKcR9fs524k2D9kp-0Nf3THDPQYLpraGyPViwfBHdUcDC6BBb40-b0sQ" ist ungültig.

What am i doing wrong?
Greetings, Karsten.

Comment: What version of the EWS Managed API are you using ? looks like (because you using async code) you using someone's port (eg what the nuget package you using) ? your token is valid but i would say they have a bug in the oAuthCredentials class of the port https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Credentials/OAuthCredentials.cs if your using the official version some people have reported issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/224

Comment: Ah, thats the point.... I have changed from "Microsoft Exchange Managed API  Version 2.2.1 17.03.2021" to "Microsoft Exchange Webservice 15.00.0913.015 19.12.2014" and now this error is gone... I receive now a new exception, which says "... 403 - Unzulässig" but this may caused by the AD-Configuration. I check this. Greetings, Karsten.